# How to stop my crawler from logging duplicates?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to know how do I stop it logging the same url more than once?

This is my code so far:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class MyItem(Item):
    url=Field()

class someSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "My script"
  domain=raw_input("Enter the domain:\n")
  allowed_domains = [domain]
  starting_url=raw_input("Enter the starting url with protocol:\n")
  start_urls = [starting_url]
  f=open("items.txt","w")

  rules = (Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=(domain)), callback='parse_obj', follow=True),)


  def parse_obj(self,response):
    for link in LxmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=(self.domain)).extract_links(response):
        item = MyItem()
        item['url'] = link.url
        self.f.write(item['url']+"\n")
```

Right now it will do thousands of duplicates for a single link, in for example,  a vBulletin forum with around 250,000 posts.

**Edit:**
Do note that the cralwer will get millions upon millions of links. 
Hence I would need the code to be really quick in checking.

Comment: Sounds like you are building an ugly bot. Crawling for email addresses maybe ?

Comment: Nope. It's for my OWN website. I need the forum urls to be obtained, so I upload into an archive website.

Comment: Have you considered keeping your URLs in a `set()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list of already visited urls and check it for every URL. So after parsing particular URL add it to the list. Before visiting a page on newly found URL check if this URL already in that list and either parse it and add or skip.

I.e.:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class MyItem(Item):
    url=Field()

class someSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "My script"
  domain=raw_input("Enter the domain:\n")
  allowed_domains = [domain]
  starting_url=raw_input("Enter the starting url with protocol:\n")
  start_urls = [starting_url]
  items=[] #list with your URLs
  f=open("items.txt","w")

  rules = (Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=(domain)), callback='parse_obj', follow=True),)


  def parse_obj(self,response):
    for link in LxmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=(self.domain)).extract_links(response):
        if link not in self.items: #check if it's already parsed
            self.items.append(link)   #add to list if it's not parsed yet
            #do your job on adding it to a file
            item = MyItem()
            item['url'] = link.url
            self.f.write(item['url']+"\n")
```

Dictionary version:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class MyItem(Item):
    url=Field()

class someSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "My script"
  domain=raw_input("Enter the domain:\n")
  allowed_domains = [domain]
  starting_url=raw_input("Enter the starting url with protocol:\n")
  start_urls = [starting_url]
  items={} #dictionary with your URLs as keys
  f=open("items.txt","w")

  rules = (Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=(domain)), callback='parse_obj', follow=True),)


  def parse_obj(self,response):
    for link in LxmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=(self.domain)).extract_links(response):
        if link not in self.items: #check if it's already parsed
            self.items[link]=1  #add to dictionary as key if it's not parsed yet (stored value can be anything)
            #do your job on adding it to a file
            item = MyItem()
            item['url'] = link.url
            self.f.write(item['url']+"\n")
```

P.S. You can also collect `items` first and then write it to a file.

There are many other improvements to be made to this code, but I leave that to you to study.

Comment: Partly good idea. A better one would be to hash the visited url and check for its existance in an hasmap with O(1) instead.

Comment: You can use a python dictionary, store the url's as keys and then do something like `if url in myDict: continue else myDict[url] = true ... (rest of your code)`.

Comment: Indeed dictionary might be faster.

Comment: How would I set up a python dictionary & store urls as keys? And if I wanted the files back as their original input on a text editor, what would I do? I'd be ever so grateful, if you could post the code edits that I'd need to do to my code.

Comment: See above, I added dict version.

Comment: If you'll have memory problems with storing big list/dict, you can use file in, say, "a+" mode and check it everytime, but that will be slower.

Comment: Thanks. I've done some initial testing and it seems to be doing the trick.